# How to use three background images in a single div to emulate a shadow

Tags: html, css

I am building an accordion menu who's height changes when menu elements are opened/closed, and want a shadow on the side of the menu.

I have three images to use as background images to emulate the shadow effect (one each for the top and bottom, and one for the middle which will be repeated in the y dimension). Currently I have set a background image for the top left, and bottom left, but can't figure out how to make the middle shadow repeat to fill the gap.

Any suggestions?

```
background: url('/devassets/content_shadow_top.png') left top no-repeat,  url('/devassets/content_shadow_bottom.png') left bottom no-repeat;
```

Comment: have you considered just going with CSS box-shadow property?

Answer (score 1):

**CSS Shadows**

```
    /*  Box Shadow, To Do: IE hack using filters */
    -moz-box-shadow: 2px 0 3px #000, -2px 0 3px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 0 3px #000, -2px 0 3px #000;
    box-shadow: 2px 0 3px #000, -2px 0 3px #000;
```

There's no reason to use images unless your shadow is really really complicated.

More info at [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/).

Comment: while I completely agree that CSS is the way to go for shadows, your example is about rounding corners.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this with extra markup. Create a new element to contain each of the images, and position them as necessary to achieve the effect.

Comment: So, lets say I need three divs, all 5px wide and stacked vertically. Now lets assume the top and bottom div are 200px each, and the parent div is 1000px. How can the middle div automatically fill the 600px of middle-space?

How do I format my divs to do this?

Comment: Just supply a height for the middle div: `<div style="height: 600px">`

Comment: but what if the height is changing as the parent div grows due to the menu expanding?

Comment: again, CSS is the way to go. Old versions of IE can't do the CSS shadow, but they also can't handle background transparent PNGs either, so neither solution is good for old IE anyways. Given that, go with CSS. I'll keep you much saner. ;)